# The best way to speed up the queue with many consumers in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, producer-consumer

I am having one multiprocess.Queue serving a large amount of consumers with quick job that causes many of them are queuing up to get() task from the Queue.

I have tried to spread out the tasks into multiple multiprocess.Queue, but it seems like not much different as they are in the same process.

The get() process speed for both of the cases are the same as it reaches the max CPU timing of a core

I have then tried multiprocess.Manager().Queue. This would for sure split each queue object into individual process. but it seems like the entire process for the programme slowed down, as well as .put() task.

Is there any possible way to speed it up? by having multiple queue?

Comment: Can you give each consumer 10 quick jobs to do so they don't visit the queue as often? Would concurrent.Futures ProcessPoolExecutor help [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py)?

Comment: Your consumers are instrumented to document time spent *queuing up*?